# Using two queries in the same controller for same view using - User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Having problems; using both queries in the same controller for the same view.

First query

```
var results = from b in db.tbl_Rough
                   .Where(c => c.tbl_Assoc.Username == User.Identity.Name)
                   select b;
```

Second query

```
 var results1 = from  c in db.tbl_Rough
                    .Where(c => c.tbl_Cous.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                       select c;
```

Both of the above queries work fine. What I am trying to do is combine them so they work in the same view. Both queries need to be checked to see if the users have data.

Comment: What do you mean by combining them? To have one set of results? (i.e. one linq query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking your

> "Both queries need to be checked to see if the users have data"

and come out with

```
var resultAll = from all in db.tbl_Rough
                .Where(c => c.tbl_Assoc.Username == User.Identify.Name && c.tbl_Cous.UserName == User.Identify.Name)
                select all;
```

Comment: And if not, it's probably `||` instead of `&&`